# Cant find variable Angular JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, coffeescript

I was following railscasts #405 on angular js and the code he uses is as follows

```
app = angular.module("Raffler", ["ngResource"])

app.factory "Entry", ["$resource", ($resource) ->
  $resource("/entries/:id", {id: "@id"}, {update: {method: "PUT"}})
]

@RaffleCtrl = ["$scope", "Entry", ($scope, Entry) ->
  $scope.entries = Entry.query()

  $scope.addEntry = ->
    entry = Entry.save($scope.newEntry)
    $scope.entries.push(entry)
    $scope.newEntry = {}

  $scope.drawWinner = ->
    pool = []
    angular.forEach $scope.entries, (entry) ->
      pool.push(entry) if !entry.winner
    if pool.length > 0
      entry = pool[Math.floor(Math.random()*pool.length)]
      entry.winner = true
      entry.$update()
      $scope.lastWinner = entry
]
```

I tried to implement something very similar in my application with practically the same code the only issue is that when the drawWinner function is called my browser logs the error "cant find the variable entry" but the variable entry was declared in the function addEntry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is functionally scoped. The entry in addEntry is scoped to the function referenced by $scope.addEntry and is not the same as the variable created by the forEach loop... You need to re-check your variable scope.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope

Comment: Thanks it worked like a charm I ended up putting the variable as $scope.entry